# typescript transpilation breaking

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, transpiler

**Problem statement :**

Define a variable with type `number` but when assign any string into this variable and try to `transpile` it into JavaScript. `Transpiler` not giving any error.

**Problem Demonstration :**

> **class.ts**

```
class User {
    age:number;
    name:string;
    phone:number | string;

    constructor(a, n, p) {
        this.age = a;
        this.name = n;
        this.phone = p;
    }

    getDetails() {
        return "Age : " + this.age + ", Name : " + this.name + ", Phone : " + this.phone;
    }
}

var firstUser = new User("27", "Rohit", "945*****44");

console.log(firstUser.getDetails());
```

In above code, We defined the `age` variable as `number` but while creating the instance of the class `User` i am passing age as `"27"` which is string. Hence, while transpilation it should thrown error but it is transpiled into JavaScript without any errors.

**Transpilation Output :**

[image]

But in the same code base if I directly assign the string to `this.age` variable in the constructor function. Transpiler throws an error.

> **class.ts**

```
class User {
    age:number;
    name:string;
    phone:number | string;

    constructor(a, n, p) {
        this.age = "27";
        this.name = n;
        this.phone = p;
    }

    getDetails() {
        return "Age : " + this.age + ", Name : " + this.name + ", Phone : " + this.phone;
    }
}

var firstUser = new User("27", "Rohit", "945*****44");

console.log(firstUser.getDetails());
```

**Transpilation output :**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Your constructor has 3 parameters with no type annotation, so their implicit type will be `any`. You can assign anything to `any` (so you can assign a `string` to `any`) and you can assign from `any` (so you can assign the `number` field from the `a` parameter of type `any`). Basically in this case `any` erases the type of whatever you passed in.

Since `a` should be a number we should provide an explicit annotation and then we will get an error when we pass in a `string` (and this is the expected behavior)

```
class User {
    age:number;
    name:string;
    phone:number | string;

    constructor(a: number, n: string, p: number | string) {
        this.age = a;
        this.name = n;
        this.phone = p;
    }

    getDetails() {
        return "Age : " + this.age + ", Name : " + this.name + ", Phone : " + this.phone;
    }
}

var firstUser = new User("27", "Rohit", "945*****44"); // error
var secondUser = new User(27, "Rohit", "945*****44"); // ok
```

You can avoid having to specify the type twice and doing the assignment by declaring the fields as constructor arguments. The following code is equivalent to the above class:

```
class User {

    constructor(
        public age:number, // Both a constructor argument and a field declaration, the compiler will perform the this.age = age assignemet for us
        public name:string,
        public phone:number | string) {
    }

    getDetails() {
        return "Age : " + this.age + ", Name : " + this.name + ", Phone : " + this.phone;
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid having parameters and variables implicitly of type `any` you can use the `noImplicitAny` compiler option to have an error if no type annotation is specified and the type can't be inferred.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still i have one doubt, As type of `this.age` is `number`. Then if i assign `a` which is string `"27"` . how it is accepting without any compilation error ?

Comment: @RohitJindal But in your code the type of `a` is `any` (because you did not specify any other type for it), so the compiler does not track that at some point you in your code you assign `"27"` to `a` and then you assign `a` to place that requires a number and this may be problematic. It just checks can I assign `"27"` to `a`, yes since `a` is of type `any`. Can I assign `a` to `age`, yes since `a` is `any` it can be assigned to anything, so all is fine as far as TS is concerned. You need to be more strict with `a` to get meaningful errors.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Accepted as It helps me to understand the exact scenario.